# how to program selecteditem in tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

[image]

i have this tab bar i want to configure every tabBarItem in this tab bar for exemple when i select the first item i want to go to this view (My Espace) for exemple the first item

i had made this code but it didn't work !

```
  - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

    if(self.tabBar.selectedItem==[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0])
    {
        CondidatsViewController *condidatsViewController=[[CondidatsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"condidatsViewController"bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:condidatsViewController animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: no i don't use a storyboard